# how to set user for installcheck in the Makefile of a postgres extension?

Tags: postgresql, makefile, regression-testing, postgresql-extensions

I am testing an example for [creating a simple base36 PostgreSQL extensions](http://big-elephants.com/2015-10/writing-postgres-extensions-part-i/).

However, I run into problems when writing and using the unit test case (`REGRESS =`). If I use `sudo make installcheck`, there will be an error saying

> ...
>   ============== dropping database "contrib_regression" ==============
>
> psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist ... ...

It seems that PostgreSQL is trying to use the current login user to perform the test, which in this case does not exist. If I omit the `sudo` and just do `make installcheck`, it will generate a different error saying `permission denied` for something

> CREATE DATABASE ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter
>   "lc_messages" command failed: "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/psql" -X -c
>   "ALTER DATABASE \"contrib_regression\" SET lc_messages TO 'C';ALTER
>   DATABASE \"contrib_regression\" SET lc_monetary TO 'C';ALTER DATABASE
>   \"contrib_regression\" SET lc_numeric TO 'C';ALTER DATABASE
>   \"contrib_regression\" SET lc_time TO 'C';ALTER DATABASE
>   \"contrib_regression\" SET timezone_abbreviations TO 'Default';"
>   "contrib_regression"
>   /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk:272: recipe for
>   target 'installcheck' failed make: *** [installcheck] Error 2

My questions are:

**Can I specify a different user (such as a superuser) in the `Makefile` for the PostgreSQL extension?**

**Or, can I solve the problem so that a non-superuser can perform the `installcheck`?**

Note: the `Makefile` is:

```
EXTENSION = base36        # the extensions name
DATA = base36--0.0.1.sql  # script files to install
REGRESS = base36_test     # our test script file (without extension)

# postgres build stuff
PG_CONFIG = pg_config
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
include $(PGXS)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set the environment variable `PGUSER`, e.g.

```
PGUSER=foo make installcheck
```

Running `make installcheck` as root (via sudo) is quite likely the wrong thing to do.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to set this inside the `Makefile`? I might need other options such as `-h localhost` etc. Regarding the installcheck, I used `sudo` because `make install` only works for root, and I thought `installcheck` may need root as well in general. Is this generally wrong?

Comment: You can set environment variables in makefiles. But you probably shouldn't, because that will tie the package to your local environment.

Comment: make install might require sudo, but make installcheck definitely should not.